# Component working with a time probability, find out the pdf for the time of failure of the system

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a system comprising four components (A, B, C and D) connected as in the figure below.

[image]

The system is working if there is a path through working components from left to right. Suppose that components fail independently and the time to failure for each component has an exponential distribution with a mean of two years. Let T denote the time of failure for the system.

(a) Determine an expression for the probability that the system is working at time $t$, that is $P(T > t).$ Hence, give the probability density function for the time to failure of the system.

(b) Determine the mean, variance and moment generating function of the time to failure for the system.

I only know the exponential distribution equation but I have no clue on where to go from there

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The right branch, say $Y$, fails in the moment that one of the three component fails, thus it is

$$Y=\min(B,C,D)$$

and thus

$$Y\sim \text{exp}[3/2]$$

now you can derive the density of T that is

$$T=\max[A,Y]$$

I think that from this point you can conclude by yourself. If not, just look at min and max distribution of independent exponentials

---

Further hints:

Looking at the system in the picture, is has two parallel-linked branches thus the system works when at least one of the two branches works. This can be expressed by a rv that is the Max lifetime of the two branches.

Looking at the lower branch, it is composed by 3 independent series-linked components; this means that this branch works until one of the three components fails. This can be expressed be a rv that is the minimum lifetime of the 3 components.

Now min and Max of iid rv is known and the respective CDF are

$$F_{\min}=1-(1-F)^n$$

$$F_{\max}=F^n$$

or

$$F_{\max}=F_1\cdot F_2\dots\cdot F_n$$

if the rv's are independent but not identically distributed.

These are known relations but it is very easy to prove them all.

Using these concepts, you immeditately will realize that

$$F_Y(y)=1-e^{-3y/2}$$

and

$$F_T(t)=(1-e^{-t/2})(1-e^{-3t/2})$$

Now all you have to do is to derivate $F_T$ to get $f_T$ (but IMHO $F_T$ is enough to answer point a) and derive the MGF using its definition so you can immediately get any simple moment of the distribution

Comment: I havent been thought about the min and max distributions, I have been trying using the cdf of each component to calculate the probability expression, is that something you can help me with?

Comment: @RevanthKumarPerla : added a lot of details, hope now it is clear